# How do I get the URL of a LinknedIn post from the URN or id?

Tags: api, url, linkedin-api, urn

I am able to post to LinkedIn via the API and I get the URN/id of the post returned, but I don't know how to get the actual URL of the post using the returned URN. I cannot find the information anywhere in the API documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you have a share or ugcPost, the following URL is valid:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/<urn>
```

or, for embedded content:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/<urn>
```

as example:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:share:<share-id>
```

or

```
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPost:<ugc-post-id>
```

Working link from [Test Organizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations#test-organizations):

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:share:6743008621090611200