# Can you get the url of the shared content on Linkedin API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am implementing some code that posts content to the user Linkedin , the request response will have the shared object ID like "6777623868333944834".
What is weird the response does not contain a url to this shared/public object. If I check the urls of this posts from the website I see urls like

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/activity-6777623868333944834-PUJ7

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/activity-6777985031844458497-h4BO

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/activity-6777947888103243776-Yy4A

so Linkedin used the ID in the url but adds this extra 4 characters at the end.
I am wondering if I can somehow get the correct url without a new request.

I am not using any special library or SDK, just doing the requests directly,
If is not possible I am not able to find the correct API and permissions I would need to get the url if I have the ID (or urn)

Comment: Do you have already try this?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65274325/2270041

Comment: @Matteo thanks, that link helped,  not sure how and why I could not find it when searching for a result, if there will be no more official source for this then I think this could be the correct answer.

Comment: Hi @siminon314, I discover this during a lots of experiments :) I never find an official answer on this.